# Products are not getting attached with their respective index images : Modern MEAN Stack

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs, mean-stack

When I **upload** a product with it's image, first product gets uploaded also the image is uploaded to server folder, **but the image path is not attached**. Second time when I upload a new product, the product is uploaded, the image is uploaded, and also the image path is attached with second product. **But the attached path is the path of previous uploaded image, not the image that is uploaded second time**.I don't know is it related to NestJS or Angular.

**I have marked the order, in which the images are uploaded to server**

[image]

**IN the following screen shot you can see that first time the product is uploaded, image is uploaded to server(as can be seen in the `assets` folder of above screenshot),but the image or image path is or attached. And the second time after upload, the 1st uploaded image is attached instead of current 2nd image.**

[image]

**Angular code service.ts**

```
     public addbooks(books: Book): Observable<Book> {
    return this.httpclient.post<Book>(`${this.API_SERVER}/books`, books);
  }


public uploadimages(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpclient.post(
      'http://localhost:3000/images/upload',
      formData,
      {
        responseType: 'blob',
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events',
      }
    );
  }
```

**Angular Code: Uploading Logic of Product with Images component.ts**

```
imagedata?: string;
  AddbookForm = new FormGroup({
    bid: new FormControl(''),
    name: new FormControl(''),
    author: new FormControl(''),
    price: new FormControl(''),
    genres_name: new FormControl(''),
    coverimage: new FormControl(''),
  });
  constructor(private readonly apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  async addall() {
    this.uploadfile();
    this.addbooks();
  }
  addbooks() {
    this.apiService.addbooks(this.AddbookForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
      this.AddbookForm.reset();
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  uploadfile() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
      'file',
      this.AddbookForm.value.coverimage,
      this.AddbookForm.value.coverimage.originalname
    );
    this.apiService.uploadimages(formData).subscribe((res) => {});

  }

  selectimage(event: any) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files![0];
    this.AddbookForm.patchValue({ coverimage: file });
    const allowedMimeTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'];
    this.AddbookForm.get('coverimage')?.updateValueAndValidity();
    if (file && allowedMimeTypes.includes(file.type)) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.imagedata = reader.result as string;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      console.log(file);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You keep posting this. Do you have a minimum reproduction to try and start debugging?

Comment: @Jay McDoniel
After 1 week of trying different things. Then posted this question. And I'm still doing the things alongside posting, that are in my approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. First I was thinking that it is backend image mapping issue. But actually the issue was here

```
ngOnInit() {}
  async addall() {
    this.uploadfile();
    this.addbooks();
  }
```

I was trying with `async` and `Observables` and searching for `state-management`. But the issue was, that I'm calling two different functions that are handling http response from server, and almost both the functions were running simultaneously. And also images take time to load and upload. So It was the issue of **Synchronization**. So I thought that I should give some time difference between the execution of the functions.

> So the solution that worked for me is `setTimeout()`

```
ngOnInit() {}
  async addall() {
    this.uploadfile();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.addbooks();
    }, 200);
  }
```

You can increase the delay time from **200**, if the image is large and takes more time to upload.